# Include a jquery ui dialog inside an existing div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a dialog that I want wrapped in a div like so.

```
<div class="myClass">
    <div id="dialog"></div>
</div>
```

All of my CSS rules have .myClass as a parent in the selector:

```
.myclass .....
```

When I call my JQuery dialog

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({})
```

it places the `id=dialog` div as its own div at the bottom of my  tag,  not inside the .myclass div.  How can I wrap the dialog in a .myclass div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, you can't do it that way. Let jquery do its thing. You should focus on the content inside.

How about the other way around:

```
<div id="dialog">
   <div class="myClass">
   </div>
</div>
```

You can modify the content inside as you wish. As far as the ui outside, the dialog box that has been themed you should simply overwrite the css rules. Well that is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to do that?  Why don't you keep your `dialog` id, and just add a class to it as well?

`<div id="dialog" class="whatever"></div>`

Comment: I am using several themeRoller themes on the same site.  Their AdvancedTheme settings allow you to add a parent class (not an additional class) to all selectors.